# MySQL variable first day of week, CROSS TAB

Tags: mysql

Need to aggregate time spent on a task by week by person (id). activity_date
ranges will change based on desired dataset. I have this:

```
SELECT id, week(activity_date, 0) WeekNumber, adddate(activity_date, INTERVAL 1-DAYOFWEEK(activity_date) DAY) WeekStart,
adddate(activity_date, INTERVAL 7-DAYOFWEEK(activity_date) DAY) WeekEnd, 
       SUM(min_spent) AS Minutes 
FROM time_spent
where activity_date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-11-10'
GROUP BY week(activity_date, 0), id
ORDER BY id, week(activity_date)
```

This works to aggregate by week, but I'd like to show the WeekStart as the column headers, cross tab.  Dates will change all the time, so specifically defining dates for columns or comparison (IF/CASE) is not an option.

```
id, minutes_week_mm/dd/yyyy, minutes_week_mm/dd/yyyy, etc...
user1, 105, 205
user2, 200, 50
user3, 25, 105
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you set custom day as week start then simply group by `DATEDIFF(table.date, @first_date) DIV 7`.

Comment: Not finding much help for this in Stack, for mySQL